# Sendmail : save email into a file

Tags: rhel, email, sendmail

I use sendmail to manage the emails of my website. I'm testing features which require to send emails, and I'd like to receive these emails in a local directory of my server, store them as text files that I can read with vi for example.

I found a way to do this a few months earlier, the emails were stored in a specific folder with the recipient address as file name. Sadly, something went wrong with my virtual machine and I had to reconfigure the whole thing. The problem is that I don't remember what I had to do in order to get my emails in my local storage, and I can't find the solution again on internet, it makes me crazy. My virtual machine is on RHEL 6.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how I did this the first time. It wasn't a sendmail configuration, but a piece of PHP code found [here](http://martinvalasek.com/blog/how-to-catch-emails-sent-with-php-on-your-local-server)
It doesn't even use sendmail anymore, sendmail path is replaced with the PHP code path in php.ini file. The emails are stored in a specific folder with the addressee's address + random characters as filename.

Answer (score 0):

Send the test e-mails to a local user, `sendmail` will deliver them locally, and you can read them as that user.

Comment: My question might be stupid, but how can I do that ?

Comment: Usually, sending the mail to a user with a domain name (e.g. bob, or root) will result in it being delivered locally.  It does depend on your sendmail configuration however.